# How to customize the letter or number appearing before an itemization in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, itemize

I am making a crossword puzzle. This requires that the itemizations skip some numbers, e.g.:

```
DOWN

1. Clue
5. Clue
6. Clue

ACROSS

2. Clue
3. Clue
4. Clue
```

Another is for an FAQ. This needs itemizations to begin with "Q" or "A":

```
Q. Question
A. Answer.
```

How can I customize the symbol appearing in from of each itemization?

Comment: MWE would have been nice...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by setting your own text for each item with the `\txt` command which takes the symbol/text as argument.

```
\starttext

DOWN

\startitemize[packed]
\txt{1.} Clue
\txt{5.} Clue
\txt{6.} Clue
\stopitemize

ACROSS

\startitemize[packed]
\txt{2.} Clue
\txt{3.} Clue
\txt{4.} Clue
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

You can change the style of the text for the item with the `style` and `color` key from `\setupitemize` (e.g. `\setupitemize[style=bold,color=red]`)

[image: Custom itemize symbols]

Answer (score 9):

For the FAQ, if it is always a `Q` followed by an `A`, you can define a custom conversion:

```
\defineconversion[FAQ][Q,A]
\defineitemgroup[FAQ][symbol=FAQ]

\starttext
\startFAQ
  \item Question
  \item Answer
  \item Question
  \item Answer
  \item Question
  \item Answer
\stopFAQ
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Cool idea! (+1)